# Split bills at home

Tags: ratio

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet to split the house bills with my SO.
I want to split the bills accordingly to our income so (the values are dummy)

`incomeA = 1000;
incomeB = 600;
percA = incomeA / (incomeA + incomeB); (0.625)
percB = incomeB / (incomeA + incomeB); (0.375)`

This is "our 50/50" and, in most of the bills is ok.
If we have a bill of 40, I will play 25 (40 * 0.625) and she will pay 15 (40 * 0.375).

Now, let's say that we have a bill that I want to pay more than the "our 50/50" (75/25, for example)
How can I translate our 50/50 ratio into that 75/25?

I don't really know how to put this in better words.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How about setting a multiplier to both 'incomeA' and 'incomeB'? The 50/50 you mention would set 'incomeA=1000*0.5=500' (the same for 'incomeB'). For the 75/25, 'incomeA=1000*0.75=750' (and similar for 'incomeB'). Good enough to get the percentages 'percA' and 'percB'. Now, I am not sure this is what you are asking.

Comment: @DavidPM yes! That works! Thanks!
can you add that comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple solution, we set a multiplier (say $\lambda_1$) to *incomeA* and another one (say $\lambda_2$) to *incomeB*, in a way that $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$ (or $100$ if it results more intuitive).

In the case of the 75/25 ratio you mention in your example, we would set

$$\text{incomeA} = 1000*\lambda_1=1000*0.75$$
$$\text{incomeB} = 600*\lambda_2=600*0.25$$

We would do the same for the 50/50 example, with $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0.5$.

The *true* amounts of *incomeA* and *incomeB* do not really matter since we are mostly interested in getting the percentages *percA* and *percB*.